# App.java is not on the classpath of project ss_d36b3017, it will not be compiled to a .class fileJava(32)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am constantly facing this error and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
App.java is not on the classpath of project ss_d36b3017, it will not be compiled to a .class fileJava(32)
```

I am using Visual Studio Code for writing Java. I have set up the environment variable. javac --version and java --version and giving the expected results in PowerShell. I am using a very simple folder convention than is made by VS Code pallet. It has 1 folder (in drive D:)named project which has 3 folder named lib(This is vacant), src(This has the App.java)<readme.md  It has no building tools. Code inside the App.java does not affect the issue.

I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two ways to see if question goes away.

1. Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace**
2. Right click the folder `src` and choose **Add Folder to Java Source Path**, then reload the window.

Comment: @Arka Singha. May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?